# Batch to move folders that are 30 days old using FORFILES

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, directory, move

I am currently working that moves ONLY folders from one directory to a folder. The current bacth file I have created is as follows.

```
Set /p target=Select Target Destination:
ForFiles /P "C:\Batch test"  /D -4 /C "CMD /C if @ISDIR==TRUE echo Move @FILE %target%" &Move @File %target%
pause
```

The problem I have is with using a target directory that has a space in it for instance "C:\Move Test". I was wondering if there was a way to still move folders to another directory that has a space in the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the double quotes with their hexadecimal equivalent 0x22:

```
ForFiles /P "C:\Batch test" /D -4 /C "CMD /C if @ISDIR==TRUE (echo Move @FILE 0x22%target%0x22 & Move @File 0x22%target%0x22)"
```

If you get problems with other characters you can also replace them; **0x26**=**&, 0x28**=**(, 0x29**=**)**.

Answer (score 0):

Your command line looks quite strange, there are several mistakes:

```
ForFiles /P "C:\Batch test"  /D -4 /C "CMD /C if @ISDIR==TRUE echo Move @FILE %target%" &Move @File %target%
```

What is wrong:

- you are talking about 30 days of age, but you specify `/D -4`, although `/D -30` was correct; note that `/D` checks for the *last modification date*, not for the creation date!
- there is an `echo` in front of the (first) `move` command, so the `move` command is displayed rather than executed; to avoid that, simply remove `echo`;
- there is a second `move` command *after* `forfiles`, as it appears behind the closing quotation mark of the `forfiles /C` part, and behind the commmand concatenation operator `&`; this is completely out of scope of `forfiles`, therefore `@file` was treated literally; the ampersand and that orphaned `move` command needs to be removed;
- to answer your **actual question**: to aviod problems with spaces (or other special characters) appearing in file/directory paths, put quotation marks around them; **but**: since that part appears within the command string after `forfiles /C`, which is already quoted, you cannot simply use `""`, you need to escape them; there are two options in `forfiles`: 1. using `\"`, and 2. using `0x22` (according to the `forfiles /?` help, you can specify characters by their hexadecimal codes in the format `0xHH`, the code `0x22` represents a `"` character); I strongly recommend option 2., because in variant 1. there still appear `"` characters that could impact the command interpreter `cmd` as it is not familiar with the `\"` escaping (its escape character is `^`);

**Thus the corrected command line looks like this:**

```
ForFiles /P "C:\Batch test" /D -30 /C "CMD /C if @ISDIR==TRUE Move @FILE 0x22%target%0x22"
```

For the sake of completeness, this is how option 1. would look like:

```
ForFiles /P "C:\Batch test" /D -30 /C "CMD /C if @ISDIR==TRUE Move @FILE \"%target%\""
```

Note that you do not need to quote the source here, because `@FILE` (like all path-related `@`-style variables) expand to already quoted strings.